# Advection Equation Matlab Error

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I was recently writing code to solve the 1D advection equation in Matlab by Finite Differences when I was given a frustrating error in my for loop. It was pertaining to the expression: u_mat(idx,tdx+1)=u_mat(idx,tdx)-v*dt^2*(u_mat(idx+dx,tdx)-2*u_mat(idx,tdx)+u_mat(idx-dx,tdx)). The error was that the index exceeded the matrix dimensions, how can I fix this? Below you’ll find my full code. Thanks in advance.

```
L = 10; %pipe length 
N = 10; %no. of nodes
v = 2; %velocity

x_vec = linspace(0,L,N)
dx = x_vec(2)-x_vec(1); 

dt = 0.1; 
t_vec = 0:dt:10;

u_mat = zeros(length(x_vec),length(t_vec));
u_mat(1,:) = 200; %dirichlet condition for left end
u_mat(end,:) =100; %dirichlet condition for right end

for tdx = 1:length(t_vec)-1 %integrator integrates to tdx+1
   for idx = 2:length(x_vec)-1              
       u_mat(idx,tdx+1) = u_mat(idx,tdx) - v*dt^2*(u_mat(idx+dx,tdx)-2*u_mat(idx,tdx)+u_mat(idx-dx,tdx));
   end
end                   

[tt,xx] = meshgrid(t_vec,x_vec);
mesh(xx,tt,u_mat)

xlabel('Position')
ylabel('Time')
zlabel('Temperature')
```

Comment: Well for one thing I see no guarantee that dx is an integer. It seems more likely that that your change in the x index should be 1.

Comment: @Ian But Why does dx have to be an integer? It’s not an index.

Comment: No, I am talking about dx not dt. You use it to shift idx but idx is an integer since it is an index. That shift should be just 1, and dx should appear elsewhere due to the discretization of the spatial derivative.

Comment: It is added to idx; the final result of that needs to be an integer.

Comment: But idx = 2:length(x_vec)-1

Comment: Oh never mind. Sorry, I didn’t see that.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and replying so quickly.